# Is it possible to pass parameter from java to xml android

Tags: java, android, xml

Im working on small app in android.. I have footer on bottom with buttons like login register search... When user is logged in I want to change button from footer.. Like button log in to view profile and button register to something else. Another buttons in footer I don't wanna change. Is it possible to send parameter like just one boolean if user is logged or not from java to layout activity xml file ?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. But with logic in java you can hide the button like

```
if(your_logic)
{
button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else
{
 button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```